# How to: get time zones in .net framework 2.0

Tags: .net, timezone

I am looking for a method which can fetch available time zones.
Using .net framework 3.5 I got method to do the same, but I am looking to fetch it using .net framework 2.0.

.net framework 3.5 specific code is as follows;

```
Dim timeZones As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo) = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
For Each timeZoneInfo As TimeZoneInfo In timeZones
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", timeZoneInfo.DisplayName)
Next
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this article contains the source that is compatible with .NET 2.0:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/TimeZoneInfo.aspx

If you grab their source you can check out how they did `GetTimeZones` method for their `TimeZone` class.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked for users with admin rights. I hope this will work with non-admin rights users.

Comment: @Vijay Balkawade: It does.