# How to create a calendar appointment with time zone support

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, outlook, html-email

I’m trying to create a new calendar event for outlook. It is created successful but when some guy from another country (another zone time) opens it, the date and time is Not correct.

Here is the code

```
Dim calendarEventText As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
calendarEventText.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Company Name")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", Convert.ToDateTime(changeStartDate.ToString)))
' I'm using the UTC time
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", Convert.ToDateTime(changeEndDate.ToString)))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("LOCATION:{0}", location.ToString))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", _mail.Body))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", _mail.Body))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", _mail.Subject))
calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", _mail.From.Address))
If _mail.To.Count > 0 Then
    calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\{0}\;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", _mail.To(0).DisplayName, _mail.To(0).Address))
Else
    calendarEventText.AppendLine(String.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\{0}\;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", "", ""))
End If
calendarEventText.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("END:VALARM")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("END:VEVENT")
calendarEventText.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR")
Dim ct As System.Net.Mime.ContentType = New System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar")
ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST")
Dim avCal As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(calendarEventText.ToString(), ct)
```

How can I add time zone support?

Enviroment:

- .NET 2.0

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the VTIMEZONE part(s) (see below) and use that timezone when specifying the times, e.g.

```
DTSTART;TZID="USA Mountain Standard Time!":20110627T080000


BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:USA Mountain Standard Time!
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, how can I get the TZID?

Comment: Use TimeZoneInfor class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979744/how-to-get-time-zones-in-net-framework-2-0) to use it in framework 2.0